# Rivers network postgis

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I try to create routing by rivers. For example I am have point A and point B (on one river or diffrent rivers). I am load osm data for region with osm2pgsql to db. I can find river "A1" near point A and river "B1" near point B , but I do not know how get route. How create river "A1" network to get routing from point A to point B ?

Answer (score 0):

All ok , I am find solution with pgrouting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).